# Difference between "Relaxed" and "Relaxing"?

Tags: word-choice

I've always been unsure of this one. I work for a holiday company and we use this word quite a lot. I never know if I should be going for "relaxed" or "relaxing". Can they be used interchangeably?

Please could someone help clear this up for me?

Here is an example:

*"This unique approach creates a **relaxed/relaxing** atmosphere that puts both parents and children immediately at ease"*

Comment: There is a big difference in principle (-ed is what it is itself, -ing is what it does to others), but in this context, that big difference doesn't really make much difference. At the end, people are relaxed.

Answer (score 2):

"relax" has two basic meanings, one that refers to the effect on people (or animals):

> - to become quiet and calm after you have been upset or nervous, or to make someone do this

If we consider this meaning, "relaxing" would be the correct adjective to express the effects above on people, and we could speak of a ***relaxing atmosphere*** to refer to an environment that invites people to relax.

The second basic meaning of "relax", in which what is affected is inanimate (laws, rules), is:

> - to make a rule or law less strict

A ***relaxed atmosphere*** would then be one in which there are no strict rules to follow. Now, the noun "atmosphere" can also be deemed to include, in my opinion, the people who are around you (not only the music and the facilities). In this case, "relaxed" would refer to an animate subject.

For the reasons above, and unlike what happens with other pairs of *-ed/-ing* adjectives (*bored/boring, amused/amusing, interested/interesting*), I think both "relaxed atmosphere" and "relaxing atmosphere" work, though with slighly different meanings:

- relaxed atmosphere: the atmosphere is already relaxed and its effect is catching.
- relaxing atmosphere: the atmosphere helps or induces people to relax.